# Android native add Contact activity architecture

Tags: android, listview, contacts, tablelayout

In our project, we are trying to impelement an activity for creating a new contact just like the one in the Android native Contacts application. There are some dynamically added contact fields like mobile, home, fax. How are they implemented?
Are they items of a list view or rows of a table layout?

Thank you

Comment: Call Android native activity using  `Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,Contacts.CONTENT_URI)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we are trying to implement a similar activity but with more features and options, so i would like to know the architecture of that native activity.